# populating table view with json data swift 4

Tags: json, swift, uitableview

I have got json data and I can parse the first part which is nav and name, however I need to parse the array `children` into a table view.

```
{
"nav": [
    {
        "name": "Home",
        "navigationName": "Home",
        "icon": null,
        "navigation": {
            "URI": null,
            "type": "CUSTOM",
            "target": "home",
            "depth": null,
            "data": null,
            "filters": {},
            "urlStructure": {
                "title": null,
                "isFeatured": false,
                "isCampaign": false
            }
        },
        "styles": []
    },
    {
        "name": "New In",
        "navigationName": "New In",
        "icon": null,
        "navigation": {
            "URI": null,
            "type": "NO_LINK",
            "target": "",
            "depth": null,
            "data": null,
            "filters": {},
            "urlStructure": {
                "title": null,
                "isFeatured": false,
                "isCampaign": false
            }
        },
        "styles": [
            "linkNewin"
        ],
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "New In Mens",
                "navigationName": "New In Mens",
                "icon": null,
                "navigation": {
                    "URI": "/men?facet:new=latest&sort=latest",
                    "type": "CATEGORY",
                    "target": "men",
                    "depth": null,
                    "data": null,
                    "filters": {
                        "facet:new": "latest",
                        "sort": "latest"
                    },
                    "urlStructure": {
                        "title": null,
                        "isFeatured": false,
                        "isCampaign": false
                    }
                },
                "styles": [
                    "linkNewin"
                ]
            },
```

That is the json data. I have parsed and populated the first name in the array nav, but cannot do it for the Children array.

I have created this data model so far:

```
struct Menu: Codable {
    var nav = [Menus]()
}

struct Menus: Codable {
    var name: String
    var children: ChildrensNames
}

struct ChildrensNames: Codable {
    var name: String
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

I have got the structs working so when I add a break point in I can see the children's names, however I do not know how to access these and add them to a second section in. Below is my table view set up

```
extension MenuViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if section == 0{
    return self.menu?.nav.count ?? 0
    } else if section == 1 {
        return self.menuItems?.children?.count ?? 0
    } else {
        return 2
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell.init(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    let navItem = self.menu?.nav[indexPath.row].name
    let childItem = self.menu?.nav[indexPath.row].children


    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        cell?.textLabel?.text = navItem
        break
    case 1:
//      cell?.textLabel?.text =

        break
    default:
        break
}


    cell?.accessoryView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "icons8-chevron-right-50"))


    return cell!
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing nested JSON using Codable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53235000/parsing-nested-json-using-codable)

Answer (score 1):

First of all let's rename `Menus` to avoid confusion. Let's name it `NavigationItem`.

The value for key `children` is also an array of `NavigationItem` and as some dictionaries don't have children make it optional.

If the structs are read-only adopt only `Decodable` and declare the struct members as constants.

```
struct Menu: Decodable {
    let nav : [NavigationItem] // Don't declare this struct member as empty array
}

struct NavigationItem : Decodable {
    let name : String
    let navigationName : String
    let children : [NavigationItem]?
}
```

Comment: ok i have done that, how i would i then get the data from children and populate that in a table view?

Comment: It depends on the data source structure of the table view. Basically use two for loops to iterate `nav` and `children`

Comment: let navItem = self.menu?.nav[indexPath.row].name
        
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            cell?.textLabel?.text = navItem
            break
        case 1:
        
            for _ in navItem! {
                if self.menu?.nav[indexPath.row].children == nil {
                    return cell!
                } else {
                    
                    for child in childItems! {
                        cell?.textLabel?.text =
                    }

Comment: that is what i have to populate the table at the moment, i can populate the nav name but not the child name

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53357177/edit) your question, add the code and a description about the expected sections and rows of the table view.

Comment: No, please, now you ruined the question. I wrote: **add** (not replace) the code and **add a description** (not just the code)  **about the expected sections and rows of the table view.**. I reverted the edit.

Comment: do you need any more details on this?

Answer (score 0):

In the JSON data “children” is an array，so you could try this:

```
struct Menus: Codable {
    var name: String
    var children: [ChildrensNames]  
}
```

Best Wishes!

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution - in order to decode properly you need to define the data provider successfully :

```
struct Nav: Decodable {
 let nav: [NavItem]
}

struct NavItem: Decodable {
  var name : String?
  var navigationName : String?
  var children: [ChildrenArr]
  //And so on
}
```

then you can scode it like this:

```
do {
     let nav = try JSONDecoder().decode(Nav.self, from: data)
     //Do somthing
    } catch let error{
        print(error)
    }
```

so the tableview should look like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let sectionHeaderCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Section") as! SectionTableViewCell

    sectionHeaderCell.name.text = nav?.nav[section].name

    return sectionHeaderCell
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.nav?.nav.count ?? 0
}



 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.nav?.nav[section]. children.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! ChildTableViewCell

    cell.name.text = self.nav?.nav[indexPath.section]. children[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

the arr referees to the children array 
hope this will help

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you answer, Do you have an idea about the rest of the question?

Comment: Why do you need different sections?

Comment: Because I want the children array to display in a different section, so when I can display them I’m going to make it into a expandable table view

Comment: This is children for you?:
     {
        "name": "Home",
        "navigationName": "Home",
        "icon": null,
        "navigation": {
            "URI": null,
            "type": "CUSTOM",
            "target": "home",
            "depth": null,
            "data": null,
            "filters": {},
            "urlStructure": {
                "title": null,
                "isFeatured": false,
                "isCampaign": false
            }
        },
        "styles": []
    }

Comment: for me children is: `"children": [
            {
                "name": "New In Mens",
                "navigationName": "New In Mens",
                "icon": null,
                "navigation": {
                    "URI": "/men?facet:new=latest&sort=latest",
                    "type": "CATEGORY",
                    "target": "men",
                    "depth": null,
                ]

Comment: Yeah sure, I’m not sure how to do that as I’m new to this

Comment: What? I’m not following

Comment: Dont know  either, worst case i will answer in a bit

Comment: im not sure where you are getting the section table view cell and the child table view cell from

Comment: from the nav, all is there